# Program size optimization

Tags: arduino-uno, compile, linker

I am trying to spare a few bytes of program size.
I faced a problem which I cannot understand and I hope somebody will help.

Look at this empty sketch, pleas. It takes just 444 bytes:

```
void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
}
```

However, this one – 1332 bytes already!

```
void f() {
    Serial.println(1);
}


void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Why?
It is supposed that function `f()` will be cut-off during the linkage stage. But it is not.
And what can I do to cut such things off, since they are not used in the code?

Comment: The problem is not `f()`, it's the fact you're now using the `Serial` object, which is massive.

Comment: @Majenko Is it possible to optimize it some-how?

Comment: Don't put code in that you don't need? If you want optional code use #ifdef etc to include/exclude it so the compiler never sees it.

Comment: @Majenko,
As I know, unused code must be optimized during the linkage or so.

Comment: You *may* find that making `f()` `static`, as in `static void f() {` will give the compiler enough information to recognize early on that `f` is unused and prevent it from building dependencies for `println` that it later has to work to figure out whether or not it can eliminate; this is not particularly Arduino related.

Comment: If you don't like the big `Serial`implementation, you may want to implement some bare-metal UART driver, like in https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/Serial_UART_Interface_with_AVR.

Answer (score 7):

Using the `Serial` object pulls HardwareSerial0.o into your program
linkage. This file defines, among other things, the ISRs (interrupt
service routines) associated with the serial port. ISRs are defined
using [the `ISR()` macro](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) from the acr-libc. This macro creates a
function prototype and assigns some attributes to the function,
including [the `used` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-unused-function-attribute) which tells the linker that it
should consider the function to be used, even if it cannot spot a single
call to it within the compiled program. The ISR cannot then be removed,
and it in turn keeps lots of code from the `Serial` implementation.

**Edit**: As pointed out by the busybee in a comment, although `f()`
cannot be removed at link time, it can be removed at compile time if you
give it the `static` qualifier. This has the added benefit of triggering
a compiler warning:

> **warning**: '*void f()*' defined but not used [**-Wunused-function**]

Comment: You might like to add that the missing `static` forces the compiler to include `f()` in the first place. All other stuff is then pulled in by this.

Comment: @thebusybee: Right, I edited my answer.